# Kurento - Error code 4: Stream doesn't contain enough data. Invalid URI

Tags: java, video-streaming, kurento

I have cloned repo with kurento tutorials from `https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-java`.
I have subproject 'player' up and running. Given a video URL, the player can stream video from it.
[image]

I have got a set of videos that I would like to be streamed via Kurento.
I created an empty spring boot project, put a video under src/main/resources/static/videos/ and tried to paste link http://localhost:8080/videos/test.mp4, but it produced the following output:

```
2023-11-16 10:15:56.380  INFO 18244 --- [EventExec-e2-t6] o.kurento.tutorial.player.PlayerHandler  : ErrorEvent: Error code 4: Stream doesn't contain enough data., source: kmsplayerendpoint0, element: kmsplayerendpoint0, debug info: gsttypefindelement.c(986): gst_type_find_element_chain_do_typefinding (): /GstPipeline:internalpipeline/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstTypeFindElement:typefindelement0:
Can't typefind stream
2023-11-16 10:15:56.382  INFO 18244 --- [EventExec-e2-t5] o.kurento.tutorial.player.PlayerHandler  : ErrorEvent: Invalid URI
2023-11-16 10:15:56.382  INFO 18244 --- [ventExec-e2-t10] o.kurento.tutorial.player.PlayerHandler  : ErrorEvent: Invalid URI
```

I tried to think of reasons why would Kurento accept some URLs and not others.
Maybe it looks for some response headers?
I made requests to two accepted URLs and started to look for response headers that were common among the two.
I noticed Accept-Ranges header.
[image]
[image]

Any help is appreciated